# How to properly animate scaling UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` and I want to scale it up and down with animation, I tried to scale it like other `UIView`s, like this:

```
self.textView.widthConstraint.constant = newWidth

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}, completion: nil)
```

The animation is a bit weird: the text in the text view is always the same size from the beginning of the animation till the end, with the container scaling up the text simply goes from right to left.

What's the proper way to scale a `UITextView` along with the text it contains?

Comment: Please add screen shots or code.

Comment: "I tried to scale it like other UIViews" tells us nothing on how YOU specifically did it. You need to explain better what exactly did you do.

Comment: Why isn't `self.textView.widthConstraint.constant = newWidth` inside the animation block?

Comment: @meaning-matters it doesn't matter where you put that line of code, all that matters is where you put `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @BrightFuture That surprized me. But it makes sense because the animation just looks at changed values. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to animate the `UITextView` scaling, I think it would be better to use `CGAffineTransform`. You can do it something like this...

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
    self.textView.transform = self.textView.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with auto layout constraints

Comment: can you explain whats the problem? it should be working .. and if you have used the same scale `0.2`, it should shrink you textview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.textView.widthConstraint.constant = newWidth
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
    self.textView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

### Update

According to [this SO post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169092/5546312), you have to use `Affine Transform`:

> The Affine Transform scaling factor is applied to text like anything else. So the onscreen text size should be the nominal textsize times the scaling factor.